# can't get iScroll to properly scroll the div with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, mobile-website, iscroll4

I'm using jQuery Mobile to build up a mobile website.
On one page I have a bunch of texts to display in a div.
I coded according to [the simple example of iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/).

I get it right in my Chrome Browser, but when I test it in mobile safari, I can swipe down the text a bit but it will bounce back, rather than scroll down.

Here's the HTML Markup:

```html
<div data-role="content">       
        <div class="text-content-wrapper">
            <div id="scroll-wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                    <li>Content</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the CSS is:

```css
.text-content-wrapper {
width: 80%;
height: 240px;
position: absolute;
left: 35px;
top: 65px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 10px 0;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
z-index: 1;
}

#scroll-wrapper ul{
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
height: 360px;
}
```

**If I move the position: absolute to #scroll-wrapper, it won't even work in the chrome.**

And use the iScroll:

```js
var myScroll1;
function loaded() {
myScroll1 = new iScroll('scroll-wrapper');
}
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);
```

Comment: Have you looked at jQM scrollview? http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/